# HighCharts Heatmap with motion

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, heatmap

Need to create a motion High Chart, i have made a fiddle to explain what i have done yet.
But need to make work the motion play button which is not working, motion will work on clicking the button and it will change the boxes color depends on the random value, motion bar will be of time frame.

https://jsfiddle.net/4aqhB/981/

Motion and series calls :

```
    motion: {
    enabled: true,
    axisLabel: 'year',
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    series: [0],
     // The series which holds points to update
    updateInterval: 1,
    magnet: {
        type: 'both', // thumb / point / both
        round: 'floor', // ceil / floor / round
        smoothThumb: true, // defaults to true
        step: 0.01
    }
},
    series: [{
        name: 'Heat Map',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [[0,0,10],[1,0,5],[2,0,3]],
        }]
```

Answer (score 0):

A heatmap point has structure like this:

```
{
  x: Number
  y: Number
  value: Number
  ...
}
```

Additionally, for the motion plugin the point requires `sequence` property which is an array of heatmap points - it might be a partial object - if you want to update the point's value (color on heatmap) then the point in the sequence should be like this:

```
{ value: Number }
```

Example of the series:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Heat Map',
  borderWidth: 1,
  data: [{
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    sequence: [{
      value: 10
    }, {
      value: Math.random() * 10
    }, {
      value: Math.random() * 10
    }]
  }, {
    x: 1,
    y: 0,
    sequence: [{
      value: 5
    }, {
      value: Math.random() * 5
    }, {
      value: Math.random() * 5
    }]
  }, {
    x: 2,
    y: 0,
    sequence: [{
      value: 3
    }, {
      value: Math.random() * 3
    }, {
      value: Math.random() * 3
    }]
  }]
}]
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/k4d8okt8/